# How do you create a stub for a database in Python?

Tags: database, python-3.x, pandas, mocking, stub

I would like to be able to create a database stub (or a mock) in order to test a function which queries the database than returns a dataframe using Pandas. Currently, I am unable to properly create a properly mocked database so a dataframe is not created as a result. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
def p2ctt_data_frame():
    conn = pyodbc.connect(
        r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
        r'DBQ=My\Path\To\Actual\Database\Access Database.accdb;'
    )

    query = 'select * from P2CTT_2016_Plus0HHs'

    df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
    return df


class TestMockDatabase(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('directory1.script1.pyodbc.connect')
    def test_mock_database(self, mock_con):

        mock_con.return_value.execute.return_value.fetchall.side_effect = [('1', '2', '3'), (1, 2, 3)]

        expected = pd.DataFrame({
            '1': [
                1
            ],
            '2': [
                1
            ],
            '3': [
                3
            ]
        })

        result = p2ctt_data_frame()

        tm.assert_frame_equal(result, expected)
```

I expect the result to match the expected as dataframe but that is not the case. Currently, I'm getting the following error:

AssertionError: DataFrame are different

DataFrame shape mismatch
[left]:  (0, 0)
[right]: (1, 3)